# UML. Название отношения классов

Tags: java, ооп, uml

Есть код на Java:

```
class A {
    private class B {
    ...
    };
};
```

Как называется отношение между этими классами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`B` является внутренним классом класса `A`. Наиболее подходящее отношение в UML - ассоциация вложенного класса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]